# Single word to describe "being made to feel inept (unjustifiably)"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for word (short phrase also acceptable) to describe being made to feel (contrary to reality) inept or stupid by something. Sort of like "gaslighting" but for matters of intelligence rather than sanity.

For example, 
"I have a PhD, but my taxes still [make me feel like an idiot even though I know I'm not] every year."

"This should be simple, but this [making me feel inept even though I'm perfectly capable] paperwork is so impenetrable."

Comment: Stultifying. Debilitating.

Comment: Life? ... forgive me. I couldn't resist.

Comment: Hello, Clare. I'm afraid this is unclear. Do you want 'a Single word to describe “something that makes one feel inept” ' or 'a word (or short phrase) to describe being made to feel (contrary to reality) inept or stupid by something'? The trigger or the experience?

Comment: Possibly "I have a PhD but my taxes still ***betray me*** every year".

Answer (score 1):

"I have a PhD, but my taxes still **confound me** every year."

> a. To throw into confusion of mind or feelings; so to surprise and confuse (a person) that he loses for the moment his presence of mind, and discernment what to do.

[**OED**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/38962?redirectedFrom=confound#eid)

> The South Dakota State Legislature never ceases to **confound me**.

[Argus Leader 20 January 2018](http://www.argusleader.com/story/opinion/readers/2018/01/20/letter-stop-wasting-time-trivial-bills/109636214/)

Answer (score 0):

*I have a PhD, but my taxes still **make me doubt myself** every year.*

*I have a PhD, but my taxes still **cause me to be racked with self-doubt** every year.*

> self-doubt.
>   NOUN.
>   Lack of confidence in oneself and one's abilities.
>   — [O-D](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/self-doubt)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two good possibilities

While neither relate directly to intellect they are both used frequently by adept people to describe situations which knock them down a notch.  The context and description of the nature of what did the humbling paint the manner of the part of one humbled.

"I usually am pretty good at reading but trying to understand tax form guidance packets always humbles me"

> [Humble at dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/humbling)
>
> verb (used with object), humbled, humbling.
>
> 6.
>   to lower in condition, importance, or dignity; abase.
>
> 7.
>   to destroy the independence, power, or will of.
>
> 8.
>   to make meek:
>   to humble one's heart.

or  Defltate, deflating

I was feeling pretty darn smart in the morning but it was deflating trying to set the clock on my vcr (lol dating myself with a vcr reference)

> [deflate at dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deflate?s=t)
>
> 2.
>   to depress or reduce (a person or a person's ego, hopes, spirits, etc.); puncture; dash:
>   Her rebuff thoroughly deflated me.

Answer (score -2):

I'll give all words & phrases which come to mind:
 Outwit, foxed a fox, threw for a loop, bested me, unbeatable, no-win situation,

Comment: It would best best to cite the sources for information supplied.